# How can I include decimals in my output as well?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So here's a piece of code that returns all numbers within a given string `s`.

```
def getDigits(s):
    answer = []
    for char in s.split(";"):
        k = ""
        for split_s in char:
            if split_s.isdigit():
                k += split_s
        if k:
            answer.append(k)
    return answer
```

However, if the input `s = 'hiking;time:106,01;distance:8.29'` is provided, for `distance:8.29`, the code returns 829 without the decimal point. How can I change my code so that if there is a decimal point in a number, the decimal point gets returned as well??

Comment: You also get `10601`, which skips over the comma. More broadly, your code always combines digits in any block of text between semicolons into a single number. Try: `s="1foo2bar3;4baz5"`

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
if split_s.isdigit() or split_s in ".,":
```

You probably want to support both decimal point and comma in order to support European locales. If you only want to support decimal point:

```
if split_s.isdigit() or split_s == ".":
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, @teambob's answer will do the job.

That being said, you have not specified what constraints exist in your input. If there is a possibility for a dot or comma outside the context of a numeric value, that will fail. Consider using regex to extract it.

```
import re

def getDigits(s):
    return re.findall('[0-9]+[\.|\,]?[0-9]*', s)
```

This code produces `['106,01', '8.29']` for your input.

Comment: It's worth noting that this *doesn't* support numbers *without* a comma or decimal point in them somewhere.

Comment: @Blckknght The group `[\.|\,]*` matches zero or more, so if there is no dot or comma, it should still work. I tested this case as well.

Comment: Oh, I guess that's true, though `?` would probably be more appropriate, since `2.,.,,,3` isn't a valid number. The other problem then is that you don't match single digit integers: `getDigits("2;3;4;5")` returns an empty list.

Comment: Just `[.,]?` works fine. No need for `|` in the character class and no need to escape the dot or comma in a character class.

Comment: Good catch guys,, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try little pythonic:

```
>>> s = 'hiking;time:106,01;distance:8.29'
>>> dict(x.split(":") for x in s.split(";")[1:])
{'distance': '8.29', 'time': '106,01'}
```